# Forecasting in time series (ARMA, GARCH etc.)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, online-algorithms

I've read here https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-forecasting.html how we do forecasting in time series models like the ARMA model, but I'm wondering if we recalculate estimates of parameters of our model after receiving a new observation?

For instance let's say that I fitted MA(2) model:
$$y_t=\mu+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} +\theta_2 \varepsilon_{t-2}$$
based on $y_1,\ldots,y_T$ and got estimates $\hat \theta_1,\ \hat \theta_2,\ \hat \mu$.  I made a prognosis
$$\hat y_{T+1}= \hat \mu+\hat \theta_1 \hat \varepsilon_{T}+\hat \theta _2 \hat \varepsilon _{T-1}.$$
Am I supposed to recalculate $\hat \theta_1,\ \hat \theta_2 $ etc. after receiving the true $y_{T+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people/tools do, some people/tools don't.

For models like ARIMA or Holt-Winters, I recommend refitting every time you get new values, for reasons detailed intuitively [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-facts-about-time-series-forecasting-that-surprise-experienced-machine-learning-practitioners-69c18ee89387).

The counter opinion, [is to do filtering, as opposed to forecasting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0701864.pdf). But my understanding is that you would have to use the state space formulation of ARIMA or similar models, as opposed to the original formulation (take this with a grain of salt, since I haven't fully grasped the topic myself yet).